# jQuery Resize and Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to create a few effects on a one-pager I am working on. I have two separate navigation bars. One is positioned absolutely (#initial) at the top of the page, while the other is fixed (#fixed_nav) to the top of the screen. The one that is fixed has two different styles depending on the screen width.

What I am trying to do is right after the user scrolls down on top of #initial, #fixed_nav slides down into view and sticks until you scroll back up and can see #initial again. I also want it to switch responsively when then window is resized, as uncommon as that may be. Individually I can get them both to work, but I've tried several different ways to make them work together and I'm only getting one or the other. I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction with this. Here's what I have right now for that part of the script:

```
//Nav Switcher
    if ($(window).width >= 940) {
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 60) {
                $('#fixed_nav').slideDown();
            } else {
                $('#fixed_nav').slideUp();
            }
        });
    }
    //Responsive
    $(document).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 940) {
            $('#fixed_nav').show();
            $('#initial').hide();
        }
    });
```

The responsive part works, but I no longer get `#fixed_nav` to slide down with a width or 940+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, instead of using javascript to do responsive tasks, use css3 media queries, the performance results will be much better.

```
/* CSS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 939px) { 
    #initial {display:none}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 940px) { 
    #fixed_nav {display:none}
}
```

Second, notice that you are **binding** the handler function of the resize only if the window width is initially >= 940. What you do want to do is bind the function anyway, and then let it run only if that condition holds:

```
// Javascript
$(document).scroll(function () {
       if ($(window).width >= 940) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 60) {
                $('#fixed_nav').slideDown();
            } else {
                $('#fixed_nav').slideUp();
            }
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked beautifully. Now I'm having another weird issue. I took out the resize in jQuery and I'm using the media queries. However, if for some reason somebody were to resize the window (like if they started <940px and maximized the window), the offsets for each link stay as they were initially. If you resize and refresh it works perfectly.